# What is the Lake of Fire?

Tags: hell, death, revelation

Revelation 20:14 is what I'm talking about. It is only confusing because nearly every translation says something like this:

> 14 And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.
>   15 And whosoever was not found written in the Book of Life was cast into the lake of fire.

First, 'death and hell' are cast in, then the wicked not found in the Book of Life.

Some translations say 'death and Hades'. The NASB says 'death and the grave'.

What kind of place consumes death, hell, the grave, and the wicked, then calls that event the second death? What is the Lake of Fire?

---

<sup>[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/508/heaven-paradise-sheol-hell-hades-the-lake-of-fire) exists but it does not have a helpful answer.</sup>

Comment: I think there are two places of torment, the Hades and the Lake of Fire. The Hades appears in [`Luke 16:23`](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+16:23&version=KJV)  (this chapter includes an interesting description of this site and the separation -gulf fixed- from the bosom of Abraham) and the Lake of Fire does not have a known location.

Comment: None of the responses deal with the lake's substance such that it explains how it consumes death and hell. Possibly, death and hell refer metaphorically to the graves and literally to the place of hell in the earth, which will be literally burned up by fire as in 2 Peter 3:12. However, earth is not mentioned as being cast into the fire.

Comment: I voted to close this question- it is at once a truth question and too broad. I noticed its pretty old, would you like to edit it?

Comment: @Andrew No. We'll see what the community will do.  Mike's answer is pretty good though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The ‘lake of fire’ is a final progression of the theological development of God’s judgment.** The ‘lake of fire’ is a final ‘hell’ which is a New Testament description of the more generic realm of the dead previously called ‘Hades or Sheol’, in the Old Testament. The Greek Old Testament uses Hades ( ᾅδης ) for the Hebrew name Sheol ( שְׁאוֹל). To fully understand the ‘lake of fire’ we need to trace the meaning of God’s judgment as ‘fire’ in the Old Testament and relate how it pertains to Sheol/Hades and Hell.

*Sheol/Hades* in the Bible is similar but not exactly the same as that found in ancient pagan philosophy.  Sheol is basically the grave with its unknown disembodied life beyond it. Originally, the idea from the lack of any further clarity is without any revelatory definition in the Bible. Like many biblical doctrines the subject is progressively revealed. In this original undefined idea, both the good and the evil went to that ‘unknown/unrevealed world’:

> before I go—and I shall not return— to the land of darkness and deep shadow, the land of gloom like thick darkness, like deep shadow without any order, where light is as thick darkness. (The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. 2001 (Job 10:21–22).)

Sheol was perceived as a place beneath the Ocean where ‘the dead tremble under the waters’ Job 26:5.

It is tempting to resist and admission to the ancient understanding of what we now call hell, because it assigned both the good and the evil to it as well as imagined silly geographical elements, which may have even been related to the view of the earth ad the center of the universe. For these and many more reasons it seems contrary to the New Testament teaching. In the New Testament the division between paradise and hell is spelled out more clearly. This was not a result of progression in human thought but as result of further revelation from God himself. On one hand Death was basically an obscure unknown in the Old Testament, therefore speculation of unrevealed details would naturally be only a little better than current Greek pagan philosophy. On the other hand the trajectory of revelation progression from God, and not from human development, included solid hints at the resurrection, such as the disappearance of Enoch, or the necessary implications of the hope of salvation whereby a return to paradise in Eden was anticipated. It is therefore not unreasonable to assume that God as he unfolds heavenly matters to humans, who in turn conjecture and imagine things along the way, to at time allude to those same half-baked speculations in further extruding his doctrines to us in clarities never imagined by the human heart.  This is essentially what happens at the time of Christ, for in between the last book of the Old Testament and the Gospels; popular rabbinical writings had already speculated a great del about paradise and the idea of Sheol was becoming more and more a concept that included only the wicked. Somehow speculation about the unknown was to a certain degree scripturally inspired and sanctified and extended by Jesus himself into a modern New Testament higher definition.

**At the time of Christ** Hades was still referred to, for example in Luke 16:23, where the rich man is there in Hades, while Lazarus is like a child in the lap of Abraham. Also, when Peter made his confession the ‘gates of Hades’ could not stand against the church. Clearly Hades has become another name for hell where only the disembodied wicked live. While paradise is the place for the disembodied righteous, such as the place where the thief next to Jesus on the cross was to go that ‘very same day.’ However, Jesus often referred to hell under different imagery that moves beyond the general abstract notion of Hades. Jesus often referred to hell as a fiery place called “Gehenna”. Hades was also considered to be a place of ‘fire’ but Gehenna amplifies the fiery aspect.

> “Gehenna” (Hebrew “Hinnom”), the name of a valley south of Jerusalem. The valley was noted in the OT period for the abomination of child sacrifices (2 Kgs 16:3; 21:6; 23:10) and in the NT period for its smoldering garbage. (Elwell, W. A., & Beitzel, B. J. (1988). Baker encyclopedia of the Bible (592).)

The Lake of fire is essentially the final development of the concept of the judgment of Gehenna. We can imagine hell as temporary steam of fiery judgments, which will flow into the final basin.  It is a full lake of hell, meaning there is no further judgment to occur, as it is complete and endless without any adjustments. It is ‘forever and ever’ that the wicked will be burdened under a full awareness of their just desert and where the ‘weeping and gnashing’ of their ‘teeth’ (a cliché for sorrow and angry frustration) due to being eternally separated from the creator is forever felt.

**If we trace the imagery of fire using Sodom and Gomorrah as well as the altar of the temple court we find that it represents God’s eternal judgment on sin.** The lake of fire includes ‘brimstone’ and so we find one of the very first lively ideas of the lake of fire in his destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah, for we see ‘the Lord rained brimstone and fire on Sodom and Gomorrah, from the Lord out of the heavens’ (Gen 19:24). In addition according to Jude, Sodom is to be understood as ‘eternal’, for hose that died under that fire ‘serve as an example by undergoing a punishment of *eternal fire*’ (Jude 7). Then again, God is in himself and his own just nature the ‘consuming fire’. (Heb 12:29).  We see it everywhere in the Old Testament for in the daily practice of the altar ceremonies, justice punishes sin in the ‘fire’ upon the sacrifices.  ‘Fire’ was God’s anger inflicting judicial punishment upon the sinner, or more correctly, the animal in the sinners place. This occurred every day in the temple.

In the prophetic books we find further supporting evidence of the New Testament high definition view of the lake of fire. In Isaiah we see the phrase that Jesus commonly referred to in his parables:

> “And they shall go out and look on the dead bodies of the men who have rebelled against me. For *their worm shall not die, their fire shall not be quenched*, and they shall be an abhorrence to all flesh.” (The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. 2001 ,Is 66:24)

In Daniel 7:10 ‘A river of fire was flowing, coming out from before him’. That is Christ is seated on a throne and the lake of fire is that body of fire flowing out from his throne to judge his enemies. (As an aside, to maintain information of pagan thoughts that scripture is still free to borrow when beneficial in extruding it doctrine out from the elements of knowledge within men’s understanding, this imagery has a specific parallel to another Greek idea of a ‘river of fire’ beneath the earth that emptied out into a lake called Tartarus, which is also referred to by ‘hell’ in 2 Peter 2:4)

**In summary, the ‘lake of fire’ is that final development of the concept of eternal death under the punishment of God. Sin, death, hell, devils, sinners and all the garbage that Jews used to throw into Gehenna ‘for burning’ will forever rest in a broad final ‘lake’ flowing out of God’s eternal throne of judgment.** The fact that is also has brimstone in it, indicates the original horror and ‘stench to the senses’ of that molten fire that rained down on Sodom. ‘Brimstone’ or ‘sulfur’ is that rock that slowly burns and melts making a rotten egg like smell. It does not sound good.  What this fire is, in terms of literal location, experience and suffering is not even slightly indicated in the Bible. We are to read between the lines of the images and humbly accept that we can only vainly imagine. However, as the wicked are resurrected with ‘spiritual bodies’, analogous to the ones we have on earth, it seems that the wicked will at a minimum have bodies that can endure this punishment whatever it is. The wicked are raised to pay for their sin and they must have bodies capable for the task. A human body would probably collapse just at the thought of approaching God’s throne let alone understanding, accepting and paying with full regret for a wasted life. This is truly a prophecy of warning concerning the end of the world for those outside of Christ. At the same time is a great comfort to those who are in Christ, for whose name they suffer the hatred of the world. He who has an ear to hear…

Comment: I was hesitant to read this at first because it was long and seemed rambling. I just finally read it and gave +1. If it were more concise and organized I might select.

Comment: @fredsbend - Hard work! I tried. For some reason I find this subject hard to trace as it takes a lot of twists and turns in the Bible.

Comment: @Mike. You mentioned the "gates of hades." I did a phrase search in the OT Psalms and found this is a possible reference to death, not to evil spirits in hades. That is: how do you enter hades? You have to die! However, a Christian may die, but their death will not be the death-blow to the church!

Answer (score 4):

> 1 Peter 3:18 For Christ also hath once suffered for sins, the just for the unjust, that he might bring us to God, being put to death in the flesh, but quickened by the Spirit:
>
> 19 By which also he went and preached unto the spirits in prison;

This place that Jesus, while he was dead, went to preach to the spirits in prison, may be Hades or Paradise.  It seems that Paradise and Hades may be separated by a some sort of chasm but near enough for communication between the two places.

> Luke 16: 22 So it was that the beggar died, and was carried by the angels to Abraham’s bosom. The rich man also died and was buried. 23 And being in torments in Hades, he lifted up his eyes and saw Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom.
>
> 24 “Then he cried and said, ‘Father Abraham, have mercy on me, and send Lazarus that he may dip the tip of his finger in water and cool my tongue; for I am tormented in this flame.’ 25 But Abraham said, ‘Son, remember that in your lifetime you received your good things, and likewise Lazarus evil things; but now he is comforted and you are tormented. 26 And besides all this, between us and you there is a great gulf fixed, so that those who want to pass from here to you cannot, nor can those from there pass to us.’

Hades is a place of torment before the Great White Throne Judgement.  It seems to be a temporary place since is will eventually be thrown into The Lake of Fire.

> Rev. 21:8 But as for the cowardly, the faithless, the detestable, as for murderers, the sexually immoral, sorcerers, idolaters, and all liars, their portion will be in the lake that burns with fire and sulfur, which is the second death.
>
> Rev. 20:10 And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever.

The Lake of Fire is a place of eternal torture.  It's the place where God permanently throws everything he detests.

Answer (score 2):

I watched [a compelling lecture by Edward Fudge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHUPpmbTOV4), a Lawyer (of course he's interested in hell), and sometimes Minister, looking at the biblical and historical influences of popular theories of the "end of the wicked" (hell).
(It's one hour in length!)

He makes a very strong argument that the 'end of the wicked' is not an eternal and everlasting torment, and may simply be an *eternal end*.

> "Around the world today, evangelical Bible scholars are giving hell a
>   serious second look. Would the God who gave his Son to die for sinners
>   finally keep billions of them alive forever to torment them without
>   end? Does Holy Scripture require such a conclusion—or offer a
>   different vision? The story of how the great majority of Christians
>   came to teach unending conscious torment is as fascinating as any
>   mystery or "Who-done-it." In this lecture, Edward Fudge will identify
>   scores of generally-overlooked Scriptures, then lead a tour through
>   some paths of church history that are less well traveled, and which
>   are haunted by pagan philosophy, medieval law and Reformation
>   politics."

Comment: Fudge is absolutely right.  The meaning of HELL in the Bible is "a state of death."  There is no everlasting torture.